# How To: create a dynamic SQL statement, using either CURSOR or REFCURSOR?

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle SQL PL/SQL so please bear with me. I would like to be able to modify/update a data set (tblDATA_TEST) with particular data values from a another data set (tblMODIFY_TEST) by constructing on the fly dynamic SQL statements and executing them.

The example that I have constructed so far is based upon using a CURSOR (FOR/LOOP), but yesterday I came across an article that suggested a more appropriate solution would be to use an REFCURSOR and regerttably not having a great deal of experience with Oracle syntax I thought I'd better ask the experts, you guys, before I get lost.

The desired end result using the sample data sets would be to see the following constructed SQL statements being created and executed.

```
-- Example constucted SQL statments
-- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "tb_excl_flg" = -1 WHERE "BR_CD" = '0123';
-- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "is_hdgd_flg" = -1 WHERE "ORG_GRP_ID" = 654;
-- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "data_dte" = TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') WHERE "data_dte" = TO_DATE('3.09.2020','DD.MM.YYYY');
-- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "is_incl_flg" = -1 WHERE "data_dte" = TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY');
-- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "OUT_AMT" = 800.50 WHERE "ORG_ID" = 321;
-- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "OUT_AMT" = 500.50 WHERE "ORG_DESCR" = 'CLIENT E';
-- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "OUT_AMT" = 800.50 WHERE "CTRY_CD" = 'UK' AND "BR_CD" = '0654' AND "ORG_ID" = 888;
```

So here's the example code, consider that you have the following data set held within a table named 'tblDATA_TEST' with the following example inserted data records.

```
CREATE TABLE "tblDATA_TEST" ("data_dte" DATE, RGN_CD VARCHAR2(5), CTRY_CD VARCHAR2(5), BR_CD VARCHAR2(5), ORG_GRP_ID NUMBER, ORG_ID NUMBER, ORG_DESCR VARCHAR2(255), OUT_AMT FLOAT, "is_ovrdue_flg" NUMBER, "is_hdgd_flg" NUMBER, "tb_incl_flg" NUMBER, "tb_excl_flg" NUMBER);
INSERT INTO "tblDATA_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('30.09.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'), 'AMER', 'US', 0123, 987, 789, 'CLIENT A', 100.50, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
INSERT INTO "tblDATA_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('30.09.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'), 'AMER', 'US', 0123, 654, 456, 'CLIENT B', 200.50, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
INSERT INTO "tblDATA_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('30.09.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'), 'EMEA', 'UK', 0456, 321, 123, 'CLIENT C', 300.50, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
INSERT INTO "tblDATA_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('30.09.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'), 'EMEA', 'UK', 0456, 654, 654, 'CLIENT D', 400.50, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
INSERT INTO "tblDATA_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('30.09.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'), 'EMEA', 'UK', 0654, 321, 321, 'CLIENT E', 500.50, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
INSERT INTO "tblDATA_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('30.09.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'), 'EMEA', 'UK', 0654, 321, 888, 'CLIENT F', 600.50, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
```

and I would like to be able to update some of those data records within the tblDATA_TEST table, with the following modify data table tblMODIFY_TEST and inserted data records.

```
CREATE TABLE "tblMODIFY_TEST" ("data_dte" DATE, "mdfy_rank" NUMBER, "tbl_name" VARCHAR2(250), "fld_name" VARCHAR2(250), "fld_value" VARCHAR2(250), "reason_descr" VARCHAR2(250), "valid_dte" DATE, "criteriafld1" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE), "criteriavalue1" VARCHAR2(250), "criteriafld2" VARCHAR2(250), "criteriavalue2" VARCHAR2(250), "criteriafld3" VARCHAR2(250), "criteriavalue3" VARCHAR2(250), "criteriafld4" VARCHAR2(250), "criteriavalue4" VARCHAR2(250), "criteriafld5" VARCHAR2(250), "criteriavalue5" VARCHAR2(250));
INSERT INTO "tblMODIFY_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),    '1', 'tblDATA_TEST', 'tb_excl_flg', '-1',   'Test branch code (BR_CD), varchar data type', NULL ,'BR_CD', '0123', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
INSERT INTO "tblMODIFY_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),    '2', 'tblDATA_TEST', 'is_hdgd_flg', '-1',   'Test organisation group code (ORG_GRP_CD), number data type', NULL,    'ORG_GRP_CD', '654', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
INSERT INTO "tblMODIFY_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),    '3', 'tblDATA_TEST', 'data_dte',    '31.10.2020',   'Test data date (date_dte), date data type', NULL,  'data_dte', '30.09.2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
INSERT INTO "tblMODIFY_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),    '4', 'tblDATA_TEST', 'is_incl_flg', '-1',   'Test data date (date_dte), date data type', NULL,  'data_dte', '31.10.2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
INSERT INTO "tblMODIFY_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),    '5', 'tblDATA_TEST', 'OUT_AMT', '800.50',   'Test outstanding amount (OUT_AMT), float data type', NULL, 'ORG_ID', '321', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
INSERT INTO "tblMODIFY_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),    '6', 'tblDATA_TEST', 'OUT_AMT', '800.50',   'Test validation date, this should not get processed (valid_dte)', TO_DATE('31.08.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),  'ORG_ID', '321', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
INSERT INTO "tblMODIFY_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),    '7', 'tblDATA_TEST', 'OUT_AMT', '500.50',   'Test outstanding amount (OUT_AMT), float data type',   NULL, 'ORG_DESCR', 'CLIENT E', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
INSERT INTO "tblMODIFY_TEST" VALUES (TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'),    '8', 'tblDATA_TEST', 'OUT_AMT', '800.50',   'Test outstanding amount (OUT_AMT), float data type and multiple criteria', NULL, 'CTRY_CD', 'UK', 'BR_CD', '0654', 'ORG_ID', 888, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

take note, since the intention of MODIFY dynamic query process is to be generic/universal i.e. to be able to update any field value in any table, the modify fields that are to be used within the construction of the SQL statement are all text fields (VARCHAR), that implies that when constructing the dynamic SQL statement the process is going to have to determine what is the field data type of the table/field that is to be updated, and furthermore to determine what are the field data types of the potential numerous 'criteria fields' that are to be used.

Hence I've put a function together "fncGET_FLD_TYP" that can determine the field data type by looking at the system table USER_TAB_COLUMNS, pass the table name and field name in order to get the field data type back.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION "fncGET_FLD_TYP"("tblNAME" IN VARCHAR, "fldNAME" IN VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR AS "fldDATA_TYPE" VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
  SELECT DATA_TYPE INTO "fldDATA_TYPE" FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = "tblNAME" AND COLUMN_NAME = "fldNAME";
  RETURN "fldDATA_TYPE";
  
END;
```

for simulation purposes I've created a fuction named fncMODIFY, but I suppose ideally this would all run as stored procedure.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION "fncMODIFY"
  RETURN VARCHAR DETERMINISTIC IS
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
  fld_typ VARCHAR2(50);
  z_row NUMBER :=0;

  CURSOR c_modify IS SELECT * FROM "tblMODIFY_TEST" WHERE "valid_dte" >= "data_dte" OR "valid_dte" IS NULL ORDER BY "mdfy_rank";
   
  BEGIN  -- iterate through each of the MODIFY record set, constructing an UPDATE SQL statement on the fly and executing it, setting the table_name.field_name to the 'fld_value', (workout perhaps via a udf function the field data type & convert accordingly), based upon the criteria# fields and their values (via a function workout the field data type & convert accordingly)
    FOR r_modify IN c_modify LOOP
      sql_stmt := 'UPATE "' || r_modify."tbl_name" || '" SET "' || r_modify."fld_name" || '" = ';

      FOR Z in (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tblMODIFY_TEST') LOOP
        z_row := z_row + 1;
        
        CASE 
          WHEN Z.COLUMN_NAME = 'fld_name' THEN 
            SELECT "fncGET_FLD_TYP"(r_modify."tbl_name", r_modify."fld_name") INTO fld_typ FROM DUAL;
            CASE 
              WHEN fld_typ = 'DATE' THEN
                sql_stmt := sql_stmt || 'TO_DATE(<fld_value>, ''DD.MM.YYYY'')';
                
              WHEN fld_typ IN('FLOAT', 'NUMBER') THEN
                --sql_stmt := sql_stmt || 'TO_NUMBER(<fld_value>)';
                sql_stmt := sql_stmt || '<fld_value>';
                              
              ELSE --'VARCHAR2'
                sql_stmt := sql_stmt || ' ''<fld_value>''' || fld_typ ; 
                
            END CASE;
      
            sql_stmt := REPLACE(sql_stmt, '<fld_value>', r_modify."fld_value");
            

          WHEN SUBSTR(Z.COLUMN_NAME,1,11) =  'criteriafld' THEN -- AND r_modify.COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF z_row = 8 THEN
              sql_stmt := sql_stmt || ' WHERE <criteriafld#> = ';
                
            ELSIF z_row > 8 THEN 
              sql_stmt := sql_stmt || ' AND <criteriafld#> = ';
              
            END IF;
          
            SELECT "fncGET_FLD_TYP"(r_modify."tbl_name", Z.COLUMN_NAME) INTO fld_typ FROM DUAL;
            CASE 
              WHEN fld_typ = 'DATE' THEN
                sql_stmt := sql_stmt || 'TO_DATE(<criteriavalue#>, ''DD.MM.YYYY'')';
              
              WHEN fld_typ IN ('FLOAT','NUMBER') THEN
                --sql_stmt := sql_stmt || 'TO_NUMBER(<criteriavalue#>)';
                sql_stmt := sql_stmt || '<criteriavalue#>';
                            
              ELSE -- 'VARCHAR2'
                sql_stmt := sql_stmt || '<criteriavalue#>';
              
            END CASE;

            sql_stmt := sql_stmt || fld_typ;
            --sql_stmt := REPLACE(sql_stmt, '<criteriafld#>', r_modify.criteriafldZ);
            --sql_stmt := REPLACE(sql_stmt, '<criteriavalue#>', r_modify.criteriavalueZ);

        ELSE -- DO NOTHING
          sql_stmt := sql_stmt || '';
            
        END CASE;
      END LOOP;
          
      RETURN sql_stmt || ';';
      
      -- EXECUTE.IMMEDIATELY UPDATE tbl_name SET fld_name = fld_value WHERE criteriafld1 = criterivalue1 AND criteriafld# = criterivalue# etc etc
      -- EXAMPLE MODIFY_TEST DATA
      -- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "tb_excl_flg" = -1 WHERE "BR_CD" = '0123';
      -- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "is_hdgd_flg" = -1 WHERE "ORG_GRP_ID" = 654;
      -- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "is_incl_flg" = -1 WHERE "data_dte" = TO_DATE('31.10.2020','DD.MM.YYYY');
      -- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "OUT_AMT" = 800.50 WHERE "ORG_ID" = 321;
      -- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "OUT_AMT" = 500.50 WHERE "ORG_DESCR" = 'CLIENT E';
      -- UPDATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "OUT_AMT" = 800.50 WHERE "CTRY_CD" = 'UK' AND "BR_CD" = '0654' AND    "ORG_ID" = 888;
      
      -- EXECUTE.IMMEDIATELY sql_stmt;

    END LOOP;
  END;
```

You can use the following SQL statements to see what is in each data table

```
  SELECT * FROM "tblDATA_TEST"; 
  SELECT * FROM "tblMODIFY_TEST";                                                                                                          -- Content of the tblMODIFY_TEST table
  SELECT * FROM "tblMODIFY_TEST" WHERE "valid_dte" >= "data_dte" OR "valid_dte" IS NULL ORDER BY "mdfy_rank";                         -- We only want to process modify updates that are still valid, i.e. where the validation date is in the future, or is NULL
```

and this SQL statement calls the function fncMODIFY which doesn't execute anything yet since I'm still struggling to get the correct syntax in order to be able to pass the fld_name/criteriafld# field values in order to be able to construct the WHERE criteria correctly.

```
  SELECT "fncMODIFY" FROM DUAL;                                                                                                       -- Call the fuction
```

hence the current output is:

```
  UPATE "tblDATA_TEST" SET "tb_excl_flg" = -1 WHERE <criteriafld#> = <criteriavalue#> AND <criteriafld#> = <criteriavalue#> AND <criteriafld#> = <criteriavalue#> AND <criteriafld#> = <criteriavalue#> AND <criteriafld#> = <criteriavalue#>;
```

but the desire is to get the example SQL statements above and have them actually executed.

Any asistance/guidance would be very much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Aside from your question, when working in oracle you need to _loose the double quotes_.  In orcle, double-quotes _force_ case sensitivity on object names.  This is "A Bad Thing".  If you have already created case-sensitive table and column names, I'd _strongly_ urge you to correct that _now.  It will save you much grief going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't replace `<criteriafield#>` and value with actual field name and value, so it cannot look like you wish.
2. You didn't call for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` so it was not fired and nothing happens.
3. You can avoid PL/SQL at all (your function for datatype can also be avoided) and buid all you need via single SQL statement with join on all_tab_cols. Then feed this to PL/SQL's `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and update that tables. If you'll build it as PL/SQL block with `BEGIN...END` and do `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on it, you will not need to split it into multiple statements and can create reproducible text for logging purposes (the logged code block can be executed via SQLPlus and debugged).

Also it is worth to mention that your dynamic SQL does not handle SQL injection.

**UPD**: Added a code without cursors and other row-by-row processing stuff. Finally you'll get a PL/SQL block that you need to pass to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and update your tables.

Some points to mention:

- I didn't use quoted identifiers because they will make your life a nightmare in one day. So all the content of modification table `tblMODIFY_TEST` need an update to uppercase.
- Don't play with regional formatting of dates, timestamps and numbers, use ISO format, because it is deterministic and can be read by anybody without guessing month position and group separator.
- Implement some checks on values to avoid SQL injections.

Your data is a good example of dynamic SQL issues, because it already contains invalid column names.

```sql
with unp as (
  select
    /*Turn criteria to rows, because in one day you can need more than 5*/
    mdfy_rank,
    tbl_name,
    fld_name,
    fld_value,
    criterianum,
    criteriafield,
    criteriavalue
  from tblmodify_test
  unpivot(
    (criteriafield, criteriavalue) for criterianum in (
      (criteriafld1, criteriavalue1) as 1,
      (criteriafld2, criteriavalue2) as 2,
      (criteriafld3, criteriavalue3) as 3,
      (criteriafld4, criteriavalue4) as 4,
      (criteriafld5, criteriavalue5) as 5
    )
  ) p
  where valid_dte >= data_dte or valid_dte is null
)
, prep as (
  select
    unp.tbl_name,
    unp.mdfy_rank,
    unp.fld_name,
    /*Build formatted field value*/
    case
      when atc_val.data_type like '%CHAR%'
      then '''' || fld_value || ''''
      when atc_val.data_type = 'DATE'
      then 'to_date(''' || fld_value || ''', ''dd.mm.yyyy'')'
      when atc_val.data_type in ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT', 'BINARY_FLOAT', 'BINARY_DOUBLE')
      then fld_value
    end as fld_value,
    atc_val.data_type as value_datatype,
    /*Build where clause*/
    listagg(criteriafield || ' = :wb' || criterianum, ' and ') within group (order by criterianum) as where_clause,
    /*Build formatted bind variables to get rid of infinite sequences of quotes*/
    listagg(
        /*Add quotes*/
        case
          when atc_where.data_type like '%CHAR%'
          then '''' || criteriavalue || ''''
          when atc_where.data_type = 'DATE'
          then 'to_date(''' || criteriavalue || ''', ''dd.mm.yyyy'')'
          when atc_where.data_type in ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT', 'BINARY_FLOAT', 'BINARY_DOUBLE')
          then criteriavalue
        end
      , ', ') within group (order by criterianum) as where_bind_vars
  from unp
    left join all_tab_cols atc_val
      on upper(unp.tbl_name) = atc_val.table_name
        and upper(unp.fld_name) = atc_val.column_name
    /*Check validity of columns and tables*/
    left join all_tab_cols atc_where
      on upper(unp.tbl_name) = atc_where.table_name
        and upper(unp.criteriafield) = atc_where.column_name
  group by
    tbl_name,
    mdfy_rank,
    fld_name,
    fld_value,
    atc_val.data_type
  order by
    tbl_name,
    mdfy_rank
)
select
  /*
  tbl_name,
  mdfy_rank,
  fld_name,
  fld_value,
  */
  /*Build final PL/SQL block of updates*/
  'BEGIN' || chr(10) || chr(9) ||
  listagg(
    'execute immediate ''update ' || upper(tbl_name)
      || ' set ' || fld_name || ' = :vb where '
      || where_clause || ''' using '
      || fld_value || ', ' || where_bind_vars || ';'
    , chr(10) || chr(9)
  ) within group(order by mdfy_rank)
  || chr(10) || 'END;' as stmt
from prep
```

Comment: Hi astentx, to your points 1. and 2., you may have missed my caveat statement, 'the function fncMODIFY which doesn't execute anything yet since I'm still struggling to get the correct syntax in order to be able to pass the fld_name/criteriafld# field values in order to be able to construct the WHERE criteria correctly.'

to point 3, how can the function to derive the field datatypes be avoided? Because I'm still going to have to covert the text values that are in the tblMODIFY criteriavalue# fields to their appropriate datatype of the field name that is stored in each criteriafield# or?

Comment: Hi astentx, absolutely awesome!

I now understand what you had implied by not needing a function to determine the criteria field data types, i.e. simply JOIN on the ALL_TABS_COLS table twice for both field name and criteria field name values, rather ingenious of you to think of 'unpivot' to effectively transpose the criteria field name values first and then join in order to get their associated field data types which alleviates the need for unnecessary function.

Very much appreciated and thank you.